# How do I combine the following comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I have two dictionaries created using dict comprehension. I am wondering if (a) there's a way to build it in a single pass, (b) is it advisable? and (c) is there a better approach?

```py
templates_gray = {k:cv2.imread(v, 0) for (k, v) in static_templates.items()}

img_dimension = {k:v.shape for (k, v) in templates_gray.items()}
```

Comment: You can accept whatever answer you found best.

Answer (score 2):

**A)** You most certainly can do it in one line. On your second iteration you're really only getting an attribute for each value in your dictionary.

```py
img_dimension = {k: cv2.imread(v, 0).shape for k, v in static_templates.items()}
```

**B)** It is getting a bit harder to read and I don't think I would do exactly that. You can do comprehensions over multiple lines, which might help a bit.

```py
img_dimension = {
    k: cv2.imread(v, 0).shape
    for k, v in static_templates.items()
}
```

**C)** I think what I would do is combine the comprehension with a function. This keeps the logic out of the comprehension and I think is easier to read. I don't know if defining a function will break your desire for a single line of code or not.

```py
def get_shape(v):
    x = cv2.imread(v, 0)
    return x.shape

img_dimension = {k: get_shape(v) for k, v in static_templates.items()}
```

Note: This assumes that `templates_gray` isn't something you need to use later.

Comment: I second your answer - I myself do complex comprehensions (in B format for readability) when I don't need the sub-results (as per your Note). I use C approach when I do something I want to test or could be useful in another code (library/copy-paste). +Properly done "merging" (A) as opposed to literally doing two comprehensions inside each other (like in @Prune's answer) improve the performance (1 pass through the list vs 2 passes).

Answer (score 1):

Do the direct substitution of the upper expression for `templates_gray`:

```
img_dimension = {k:v.shape for (k, v) in 
                    {k:cv2.imread(v, 0) for (k, v) in
                         static_templates.items()  
                    }.items()
                }
```

The advisability depends entirely on your usage and maintenance environment.  I find this one-line version to be less readable.  At the very least, it needs a comment to explain the holistic effect.

Comment: I agree, this one-liner is much less readable and there really is no performance improvement in this approach.

Comment: Your "one liner" doesn't improve the performance at all. It's still 2 passes through all items, while it could all be done in a single pass. Good merger of two or more comprehensions can improve the performance a lot, depending on the volume of your data.

Answer (score 0):

For (a), I would say to check the top answer, for (b), I would say, the answers are one-liners but these are basically hard to read for me. So I recommend to expand them out to make more sense. For (c), other than Jacinator's answer which actually defines a function and not just a single line of code, I don't know. I would say there might be not any but that is just my conjecture. And, it depends on your definition of "best".